# install older version of gcc - debian sid

Tags: gcc, version

I have Debian testing.
My version of gcc is :

```
gcc (Debian 6.2.1-5) 6.2.1 20161124
```

I would like to install the version 4.7 of gcc but any attempts fail. 
I added

```
deb http //ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

to have the packet available via apt-get

or I troed to download the .deb here

https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/amd64/gcc-4.7-base/download

but it fails with the error:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-4.7-base:amd64:
>   gcc-6-base:i386 (6.2.1-5) breaks gcc-4.7-base (<< 4.7.3) and is
>   installed.   Version of gcc-4.7-base:amd64 to be configured is
>   4.7.2-5.  gcc-6-base:amd64 (6.2.1-5) breaks gcc-4.7-base (<< 4.7.3) and is installed.   Version of gcc-4.7-base:amd64 to be configured is
>   4.7.2-5.
>
> dpkg: error processing package gcc-4.7-base:amd64 (--install): 
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
>   while processing:  gcc-4.7-base:amd64

The point, I can't remove gcc-6

Comment: Can you tell us why you need gcc 4.7? You could probably rebuild it from the Debian sources. This would be a "forward-port".

Comment: I would like to run SeDuMi 
http://sedumi.ie.lehigh.edu/?page_id=58

Comment: you can also build it from vanilla sources - http://fr.mirror.babylon.network/gcc/releases/gcc-4.7.0/gcc-4.7.0.tar.bz2

Comment: You could also write to the authors for help (e.g. open a Github issue). I see they are providing binaries. Are you using an older version of `gcc` to compile because it is required for compatibility with your version of Matlab, because the provided binaries require 4.7 libraries, or for some other reason?

Comment: because there binairies require 4.7... that's good idea I will do it